# Where are all the OS upgrade stations in System Shock 2?

Tags: system-shock-2

How many OS upgrade stations are there in System Shock 2 and where are they located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 OS Upgrade Stations.

The first is in MedSci, in the Medical section, near the entrance to the Crew Quarters.

The second is in Hydroponics B, on the Southeast corner, near the Bio Survey area.

The third is in Recreation C, in the Mall section.

The last of them is on the bridge of the Rickenbacker, just after you enter.